# Android recent activity displayed after intent filter activity is finished

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

So my app has a problem with 2 activities - `MainActivity` and `ShareActivity`. As you might guess, the `MainActivity` is the main activity and does most of the work. `ShareActivity` has an intent filter for receiving files. When i share something from another app, the `ShareActivity` is launched and it does it's work (user has to pick a folder there) and finishes.

If i just share something to my app, `ShareActivity` is launched, it does everything it should, it finishes and user is back in the app from which he shared the item. The problem is, if i have recently opened my app (`MainActivity` is in recent menu), when `ShareActivity` has done it's work and finishes itself, instead of showing the app from which user shared the item, `MainActivity` is displayed.

```
[Activity (
    Label = "Failiem.lv",
    NoHistory = true,
    ExcludeFromRecents = true,
    ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait
),
IntentFilter (
    new[]{Intent.ActionSend, Intent.ActionSendMultiple},
    Categories = new[]{Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryOpenable},
    DataMimeType = "*/*"
)]
public class ShareActivity {
    ...
}


[Activity (
    MainLauncher = true,
    Icon = "@mipmap/icon",
    WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan,
    ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait,          LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask
)]
public class MainActivity {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the launchmode of your shareactivity to singleTask ?

By doing this, it should not add it to the backstack of your mainactivity.

Comment: Yes, still does the same